# Removing old row dates instead adds another Tue

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro for Excel VBA to remove old promotions from an excel sheet. The date also has the day of the week before the date. The code below is supposed to remove the day of the week, which because that's when reports come out is always Tue, evaluate if it is before today, then re-add Tue at the beginning. However, instead, it fails to delete Tue from older dates, resulting in older dates saying Tue Tue, then the date. I have tried five different ways of doing this and it has all failed in multiple ways.

```
For i = 50 To 150
    Range("E" & i).Select
    Range("E" & i).Replace What:="Tue ", Replacement:=""
    If ActiveCell < Date Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    Range("E" & i).Value = "Tue " & Range("E" & i).Value
Next i
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] the question and include an example of the input and the expected output.

Comment: Put the line adding the Tue back in into an else statement. When you delete a row everything gets pushed up so youre adding the tue to a new line.

Comment: Also, do you _always_ want to insert "Tue" or do you want to insert the day name of the current date (which happens to be a Tuesday, today)?

Comment: I always want to add back Tue

Comment: I tried that, and it solved the Tue Tue issue, but it is still failing to delete older dates.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete a row all rows below it get pushed up. You need to either iterate backwards, delete all at once using a unionized range, or just put `Range("E" & i).Value = "Tue " & Range("E" & i).Value` into an else statement.

To delete the dates you'll want to convert their value to dates as they are currently strings looking like dates.

This one uses a unionized range:

```
Sub t()
Dim i As Long
Dim delrange As Range
    For i = 50 To 150
        Range("E" & i).Replace What:="Tue ", Replacement:=""
        If CDate(Range("E" & i).Value) < Date Then
            If Not delrange Is Nothing Then
                Set delrange = Union(delrange, Rows(i).EntireRow)
            Else
                Set delrange = Rows(i).EntireRow
            End If
        Else
            Range("E" & i).Value = "Tue " & Range("E" & i).Value
        End If
    Next i
    delrange.Delete

End Sub
```

I also removed your `Select` and `ActiveCell` no need for those.

Comment: I inputted your code into my macro and no dice. I then ran it by itself and it still failed to delete rows with older dates.

Comment: We need to see what your data looks like then, it works on my test sheet.

Comment: Would be better to run the loop backwards i.e. `For i = 150 To 50 Step -1`.

Comment: I can't show you the data because of company policy unfortunately. Its promotional information from retailers. Each row is a promotion and the cell I am looking at is the date that the promotion ends.

Comment: Doing it backwards did it! Thank you!